# my search algorithm causes hang

Tags: php, search

I have made a search system that compare all of the records whit the search key. when the database records increase hangs, it worked for 100 records and now its hanging for 600 records.

look at it :

```
for ($i=0;$i<$rom_num;$i++)
{
    $score = 0;
    $title = "رام ".mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT romk FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0)." ".mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT comp FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0)." ".mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT family FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0)." ".mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT model FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0)." ".mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT modnum FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0)." ".mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT androidv FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0)." ".mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT buildnum FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0)." ".mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT region FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0);
    $name = "رام ".mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT romk FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0)." اندروید ".substr(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT androidv FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0), 0,1)." برای ".mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT comp FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0)." ".mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT model FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0);
    $ser = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT ser FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0);
    $title = explode(" ",$title);
    foreach($title as $word)
    {
        $word = strtolower(str_replace("!","",$word));
        $word = str_replace("?","",$word);
        $word = str_replace("؟","",$word);
        $word = str_replace(".","",$word);
        $word = str_replace(",","",$word);
        $word = str_replace(":","",$word);
        $word = str_replace("&prime;","",$word);
        $word = str_replace("&quot;","",$word);
        $er = 1;

        foreach($keywords as $keyword)
        {
            if ($word == $keyword)
            {
                $er = 0;
            }
        }
        if ($er == 0) {
            $founded = 1;
            $score = $score + 1000;
            if ($cfm[$ser] == '') {
                $cfm[$ser] = str_replace($word,"<span class='highlight'>$word</span>",$name);
            }
            else
            {
                $cfm[$ser] = str_replace($word,"<span class='highlight'>$word</span>",$cfm[$ser]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $score = $score - 1;
        }
    }

    $results['rom:'.$ser] = $score;
    if ($score > 0) {$results_num++;}
}
```

Comment: Plz, recode parts of your code, currently your are doing sqlquerys that are the same twice. Like `mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT romk FROM $prefix"."roms ORDER BY time"),$i,0)` Why query this 2 times if one result can be used 2 times. And currently it is not really readable and no error checks are done. So its hard to tell why it `hang`

Comment: And you should use `LIMIT 1` if you only fetch one result. So currently it can be that are 200+ result rows are given, but you are using only one entry.

Comment: What you also can do is move the `$result=mysql_query()` parts above the loop. And use the result after that `mysql_result($result,$i,0)`.

Comment: tnks for answering :)